# Android programming with two pane rotates according to orientation

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I want to create two pane layout. For landscape and portrait if I rotate the screen it should automatically change its orientation. First fragment with list view and second fragment with text view matches to them.

Comment: Check the link for example http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html

Comment: i need example project #chandrakanth

Comment: In that link only you have the option to download the sample app at right side

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create **layout-land** android resource directory for landscape view under res folder in your android studio, the other **layout** folder (the default one) will behave for portrait viewing.
Check this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html for more details.